# Scraping legal disclosure reports to build a database?

Tags: united-kingdom, intellectual-property, terms-of-service

I am thinking of scraping business related data from websites like the [UK's National Storage Mechanism](http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/NSM), where all UK publicly traded security issuers must periodically report various bits of information (think of it as equivalent to the US SEC's website). I would like to collect some data from it and other similar sites, enrich the data by linking various elements together and store the result in a database for distribution.

From questions like [this one](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/2010/28209) and [that one](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/16989/28209), I understand that factual data (I am assuming that business related data such as company ownership is factual info) is not copyrightable, and the limitations to what I would like to do is in the Terms of Use of the sites I am getting information from.

Considering the ToS portion below, would the act of extracting information (for instance: extracting the name of directors from an annual report and storing it in a database) be considered as "modifying" what I have downloaded?

Also does the fact that such information must be made public by law give it any special status in terms of rights to reproduce?

> PERMITTED USES
>
> You may print off copies, and may download extracts, of any page(s) from NSM Website for your use and you may draw the attention of others to content posted on the NSM Website, subject to:
>
> - reasonable maximum network or facility limitations
> - you **may not modify the paper or digital copies of any materials you have printed off or downloaded in any way** and
> - you  may not  use  any  illustrations, photographs, video or  audio sequences  or  any  graphics separately from any accompanying text.

(from [UK NSM's Terms of Use](http://tools.morningstar.co.uk/util/GetDocument.ashx?FileId=10485))

This would be done under UK/EU law. I understand this is not legal advice, but I'm trying to figure out what questions to ask an actual lawyer.

Comment: Print this page out and take it to your lawyer :)

Comment: I will have to do that anyway :)